# meta viewport - how to show div's background in the same way on pc and mobile?

Tags: css, meta

I have the meta viewport in my page:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

And a background image in a div, I want to show the image in the same way on computer and mobile. The problem is, on mobile it is much bigger than computer like in the image below:

[image]

```
#mydiv{
 width:100%;
 height:150px;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 background-image:url(myurl.jpg);
}
```

any ideas how can my div have the same background size on computer and mobile without remove the meta viewport?

Comment: The problem here is that the screens are different sizes proportionally. You could set the box to be a different height on a mobile. Or try a different background size setting.

Comment: @Legin76 thank you, in fact I try to set a different height on mobile `@media screen and (max-width:` to 70px, it is good on my mobile... but I think it may change if one mobile has a bigger screen or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the mobile height to be smaller.

```
@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 768px) {  
    #mydiv{
        height:75px;
    }
}
```

You can set as many sizes as you want to cover lots of size screens. Remember not all computer screens are the same size either.

Comment: oh, it seems nice!! I will try this! I change cover to `auto` on mobile and in my mobile it seems nice... don't know if `auto` is a good solution but... `background-size: auto;`

Comment: Don't forget to try your phone in both portrait and landscape too. On your computer you can resize your browser window to see how it looks on different screen sizes.